# Google Chrome Error Message: "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play()"

Tags: javascript, domexception

In Google Chrome, I get this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play()

My php code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="aj('player')"></a>
```

My js code:

```
case "player":
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    var fileId = info.match(/\/view\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g)[0].substr(6),
        request.onload = successListener;  
        function successListener() {  
    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);  
    var player = '<iframe width="668" height="100" autoplay="true" frameBorder="0" src="https://'music.com/getEmbedPlayer/'+ fileId +'?width=668&autoplay=true&date='+ data.uploadDate +'"></iframe>';
```

Comment: You have a syntax error where you build the `iframe`. There's an extra quote `https://'music.com` which is breaking the string concatenation.

Comment: I know, i mistyped when i posted it here, code is working fine, just im getting this error in chrome...

Comment: anyone know the fix ?